# Referencing a JavaScript object in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm working on learning JavaScript and jQuery, and had a (probably boneheaded newbie) question. If I'm using a constructor, how do I grab something from the resulting array and reference it in jQuery, say to append it to a `<div>` in an HTML document?

Example:

```
var questGen = function (question, answer) {
var self = this;
self.Question = question;
self.Answer = answer;
};

var quizQuestion = new questGen("Question", ["Answer", "Answer 2", "Answer 3"]);
```

I can work with the DOM in JavaScript, and I've successfully made `quizQuestion` a huge array of objects and distributed them through the DOM with JavaScript, but how do I grab a `Question` out of `quizQuestion`, and append it to a `<div>` using jQuery?

EDIT: I fear I'm explaining things wrong, and I apologize, I'm super new to this stuff. What I'm wondering is how would I take `questGen.Question` from an `object` in jQuery, and then add it as text inside an HTML `<div>`.

Comment: quizQuestion is not an array of question, but an object. You are probably overriding that object. Is that your full code?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean, according to your code, quizQuestion IS a questGen, so, for example quizQuestion.Question == "Question"

Comment: What exactly do you want to append to a DIV?  Another DOM element, text?  Given an array of `questGen` objects, you'll need to create some kind of `findElement` method in your array to match based on `Question'.

Comment: No, this is just an example... I apologize if I'm explaining things wrong, I'm very new to doing this. I really just am wondering how to pull something from that object and reference it in jQuery.

Comment: What does jQuery have to do with it? It's just an object.

Comment: Why not use `$('#divID').append(quizQuestion.Question+'<br/>')` ?

Comment: @Pointy sorry, was a typo, I was typing this way too fast; I'm at work so I'm doing 50 things at once. Meant a JavaScript object.

Comment: @J148 That's what I was looking for. Like I said, I knew it was a stupid newbie question, and I probably asked it wrong... I'm just new so I had no clue how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, assuming you have an array of these objects and wish to list all the `.Question`s in a div...

JS:

```
for (var x=0;x<array.length;x++) {
    $('#divID').append(array[x].Question+'<br/>');
}
```

Or without JQuery

```
for (var x=0;x<array.length;x++) {
    document.getElementById('divID').innerHTML += (array[x].Question+'<br/>');
}
```

Comment: That's what I needed to know; again, I apologize for my crappy wording, like I said I'm super new to this and really trying to learn it.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have the following in your HTML:

```
<div id="question"></div>
```

This is the code that you already have:

```
var questGen = function (question, answer) {
    var self = this;
    self.Question = question;
    self.Answer = answer;
};
var quizQuestion = new questGen("Question", ["Answer", "Answer 2", "Answer 3"]);
```

Now you want to "grab" the *Question* out of *quizQuestion*, and append it to a  using jQuery, just simply do

```
$('#question').append(quizQuestion.Question);
```

Likewise

```
var answers = quizQuestion.Answer;
```

Now *answers* gives you an array of *["Answer", "Answer 2", "Answer 3"]*

*Answer is based on my understanding of your question which I'm not entirely sure I got correctly*

Answer (score 0):

Try

html

```
<div id="results"></div>
```

js

```
var questGen = function (question, answer) {
var self = this;
self.Question = question;
self.Answer = answer;
};

var quizQuestion = new questGen("Question", ["Answer", "Answer 2", "Answer 3"]);

$("#results")
.text(quizQuestion["Question"] +": "+ quizQuestion["Answer"].join(", "));
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/b1f3xge9/